# I don't know how to fix my code . I am trying to make a grid

Tags: jquery, for-loop, row, raphael

I'm trying to figure out how to make my code work and look like the photo attached :(

The question is:
**Create an HTML page with a text input, a button, and container for a Raphaël paper object. We will have the user enter a number in the form and click the button, and then draw an n×n grid of squares.
If the user enters 8 in the text input and clicks the button, you should draw eight rows and columns of little squares. To do this, you will need two for loops nested inside each other like this:

```
for ( row=1; ... ) {
  for ( col=1; ... ) {
    ...
  }
}
```

In the (inner-most) loop body, draw a little square on the paper with an x and y value calculated from the loop counters so the squares end up in a grid pattern.**

---

Please help me :(

I want my code to look like this :(

[image]

and this is mine

```js
x = 0
y = 0
grid = function() {
 entered_text = $('#howmany').val();
 for (row = entered_text; row <= 15; row += 1){
    for (col = entered_text; col <= 15; col += 1) {
   r = paper.rect(x, y, 20, 20);
   x = r * col
  } 
  y = r + row;
 }
}


setup = function() {
  paper = Raphael('svg', 400, 400)
  jQuery('#start').click(grid)
 
}

jQuery(document).ready(setup)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en">
<head> 
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<script src="http://cmpt165.csil.sfu.ca/js/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://cmpt165.csil.sfu.ca/js/raphael-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script src="logic.js"></script>
<title>Exercise 11</title>
</head> 
<body>
<h1>Exercise 11</h1>


<div class="gridsize">Grid Size:
<input type="text" id="howmany" />
<button id="start">Go</button></div>

<div id="svg"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

EDIT:
I don't know if my .js is correct so far to make the grid appear

Comment: Could you post the html part too?

Comment: What does it do with your code at the moment?

Comment: Add what the actual problem or error is that you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is wrong in multiple places:

1. to create the grid use:

   ```
   for (row = 1; row <= entered_text; row += 1){
       for (col = 1; col <= entered_text; col += 1) {
       }   
   }
   ```

you wrote "entered_text" in the wrong part of your for loop.

2. when you do this:

   ```
   r = paper.rect(x, y, 20, 20);
   ```

   You are storing the rect object into y. It's an object not a number.

Therefore,

```
y = r + row;
```

is like saying

```
y=car + 3
```

You cannot add "3" to "car" because 3 is a number and "car" is a thing.

Here's a working solution in [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/env6zpny/2/) with annotations.

```
var gridSize = 400
var button = document.getElementById("myButton")
button.onclick = function () {
  var text = document.getElementById("number")
  var size = text.value
  var blockSize=gridSize/size
  for(var row=1;row<=size;row++) {
    for(var col=1;col<=size;col++) {
    paper.rect((row-1)*blockSize, (col-1)*blockSize,blockSize,blockSize)
    }
  }
}
paper = Raphael('svg', gridSize, gridSize)
```